# How to fade out everything "around" a given control?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

In my application, I need some modal behavior in certain situations, i.e. the user should only be allowed to interact with a specific element of the UI (e.g. all controls inside a group box). I do not want to use modal dialogs, so I try to find a way to "fade out" everything *except* the control that should stay active, preferably by darkening everything else (thereby giving visual focus to the control in question).

How could such a behavior be achieved? Please note that the element that should become modal is at all times part of the UI, so I can't just place it on an overlay or something similar.

I've stumbled upon Decorators and Adorners, but there is rather little information on these...

Answer (score 3):

You could apply an overlay to the whole window, and set the `OpacityMask` of this overlay so that it is transparent above the element that must be modal. I'll try to post an example in a few minutes.

---

EDIT: OK, it's a bit harder than I expected... Here's a somewhat-working-but-ugly solution:

```
    private Grid _modalOverlay;

    private void btnShowOverlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_modalOverlay != null)
            root.Children.Remove(_modalOverlay);
        _modalOverlay = MakeModalOverlay(groupBox1, root, 0.5);
        root.Children.Add(_modalOverlay);
    }

    private static Grid MakeModalOverlay(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement root, double opacity)
    {
        var offset = GetRelativeOffset(element, root);

        Grid g = new Grid();

        var c0 = new ColumnDefinition();
        c0.Width = new GridLength(offset.X);
        var c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        c1.Width = new GridLength(element.ActualWidth);
        var c2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        c2.Width = new GridLength(root.ActualWidth - element.ActualWidth - offset.X);

        var r0 = new RowDefinition();
        r0.Height = new GridLength(offset.Y);
        var r1 = new RowDefinition();
        r1.Height = new GridLength(element.ActualHeight);
        var r2 = new RowDefinition();
        r2.Height = new GridLength(root.ActualHeight - element.ActualHeight - offset.Y);

        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c0);
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c2);
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(r0);
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(r1);
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(r2);

        Brush b = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) { Opacity = opacity };
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (i == 1 && j == 1)
                continue;

            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Fill = b;
            Grid.SetColumn(r, i);
            Grid.SetRow(r, j);
            g.Children.Add(r);
        }

        Panel.SetZIndex(g, int.MaxValue);

        return g;
    }

    private static Vector GetRelativeOffset(Visual visual, Visual ancestor)
    {
        Visual tmp = visual;
        Vector offset = default(Vector);
        while (tmp != ancestor)
        {
            offset += VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(tmp);

            tmp = (Visual) VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tmp);
            if (tmp == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("ancestor is not an visual ancestor of visual");
        }
        return offset;
    }

    private void btnHideOverlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_modalOverlay != null)
            root.Children.Remove(_modalOverlay);
    }
```

In the code above, `root` is the root panel of the window.

This solution kind of works, but it has two major issues:

- It doesn't support resizing; this could probably be tackled by binding the column width and row height of the overlay grid, using converters, but it's not very straightforward
- It prevents you from *clicking* other controls, but you can still interact with them using the keyboard. I think the only way to prevent this would be to actually disable them...

Comment: Handling the Window Resize event and recreating the overlay in there seems to be pretty decent performance wise, and that's without any optimization... now to find a way to easily disable all controls...

Answer (score 1):

I would go with an Adorner because it's the WPF element for which msdn specifies that can be used to "Visually mask or override part or all of a UIElement" ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

A good starting point can be found in this [blog post](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/wpf-overlays-or-better-adorner/), where you will probably want to exclude from the rendered region the area of the UIElement you want to emphasize. (At this point you can even create a VisualBrush of the entire window and paint the adorner with it, if you want to obtain a cool effect, but otherwise a solid brush with some 0.5 opacity should do it).

Thomas noted very well that when this "modal" behaviour is on, you should disable all the controls with which the user is not supposed to interact, because only disabling them guaranties that those controls do not respond to user input in any way (or at least make them unfocusable, but i think this might mess with their previous state, when you will return from the "modal" state).